# 'lib' issue with running a game outside of Steam client

Tags: linux-mint, libraries, games, steam

I am running Mint 18.2 Sonya and using the nvidia-375 drivers.

The game in question is Crusader Kings II.  From within the steam client it launches fine.  However, I would prefer not to use the client if at all possible.  I know this is possible with the Win version of CK2 by simply running the executable directly.  Running the executable `~/.steam/steam/steamapps/common/Crusader\ Kings\ II/ck2` from Thunar results in nothing, so I ran it via command-line instead and got this message:

```
./ck2: error while loading shared libraries: libuuid.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

A little searching tells me this is a missing lib file.  I found libuuid.so.1 in `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` and made a symlink from there to `/usr/lib/`

This was a fix I found from someone with a similar issue: same game, different missing lib.  Running the executable from command line again nets a new error.

```
./ck2: error while loading shared libraries: libuuid.so.1: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
```

More research shows that this means the lib that I symlinked is the wrong architecture.  Which I really should have expected since I found the thing in /lib/x86_64-blah-blah.  However now I cannot seem to find a 32-bit version of libuuid.so, I even tried symlinking it to /usr/lib32 instead, but then it goes back to complaining that the library is missing.  I checked to make sure my `multiarch-support` package is up to date, as well.

Edit: I made sure the `libuuid1` package was up to date. Here is the dpkg -L results:

```
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libuuid1
/usr/share/doc/libuuid1/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libuuid1/copyright
/lib
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1.3.0
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib32:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

This will make sure steam will look first in /usr/lib32 to find the needed libraries.

This fix worked for some users.